# What Is An Explain Word?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

This is in the idea of the What is a [Word/Group of Words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) group started by [A Person](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a new type of [Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Group of Words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) problems.

---

If a word is the best I call it an Explain word.

Use the following words to find the best words.

```
I
Don't
Know
Any
Not
Explain
Words
And
Am
Sad
About
It
```

Because I don't know any, there are no Not Explain Words in this whole problem, but there are many in the other problems.

Comment: ... wait, what?

Comment: Type Words now have Not Explain Words because type words are more important than the problem. This comment has only Explain Words.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An "Explain Word" is

> one of the ten hundred most used words. The word "Explain" comes from [Thing Explainer](https://blog.xkcd.com/?p=805), by a very well known draw-and-write person for [this computer place](http://xkcd.com).

Comment: I thought I finally got one but now I'm sad

Comment: @greenturtle3141 You almost got it! Why did you delete your answer? I would've upvoted that too.

Comment: @randal'thor I do not know your words, you will have to explain.

Comment: @djechlin: He said that the other person who figured out the answer should not have taken down his answer. It was still a good answer, even if it was too late and not completely right.